# Visual Studio 2010 data tip for conditional statements

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-debugging, datatip

I just noticed an strange regression when debugging using vs.net 2010.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;

if (a > b)
    ;
```

When debugging under visual studio 2008, if I mouse over the a variable, it would show me the value. The same for the variable b. The mind blowing feature to me was that if I mouse over the ">" operator, it would show me the result of the "a > b" expression. This is awesome!

The problem I'm having now is that it doesn't work anymore on visual studio 2010. Is this intended or is there any configuration I should do to make it work?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem with Data Tips (hovering over expressions stuff) was fixed with SP1 in VS2010. Maybe you have an outdated version? I hope this helps: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5e545b9d-36c4-45e4-8a65-b57b7dcadb24/visual-studio-2010-data-tips-are-broken?forum=debuggercanvas

Comment: You were right. After I update the sp1 it worked again. But I noticed that vs.net 2013 has the same problem. Another regression?